# How to edit schema.org markup of WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, seo

How to edit schema.org markup of WooCommerce? Especially I am looking to delete the itemprop availability or hide it from Google rich snippets, but I can't find it in the WooCommerce files.

[image]

I thought it'll be within `theme > Woocommerce > single-product >  ...`

But can't find it.

I am also happy with a hook via `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite Woocommerce templates, you can create the new directory named Woocommerce in your theme and add your customized templates here. In this case, you need to name the template files exactly as they are called in the plugin, you can [see it here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/tree/release/3.2/templates)

Schema.org markup is added by default in Woocommerce, maybe you need just update this plugin to the latest version.

Comment: thanks, but I know all this. I am looking for, where I can edit the markup from woocommerce.

Comment: The templates are where all the markup (including Schema) comes from. So, customizing those is the right way to remove whatever markup you need. Alternatively, you can look into their filters and hooks - there might be a way through `functions.php` to filter and remove the portion of schema you want to exclude.